# appending & printing a list of numbers in python

Tags: python, list

I am solving a numerical approximation (square root of two) up to a million or more digits of precision.
There is little efficiency improvement I can make because of the insufficient knowledge I guess. But I do have a few questions related to Python itself which may help reduce some overhead times ....

1. If we are doing a calculation that will last several hours,how much of a constant factor can I reduce by moving a one-time conditional statement outside the while loop (IT WILL ONLY BE USED ONCE ANYWAY)? Is it just n*constant factor C ?
2. Upon some readings, I was told that list.append(x) is costly. Inside the while loop, each iteration will append a new integer into the list (which I also have to str(x) first....). 
   def method6():

   return ''.join([`num` for num in xrange(loop_count)])

Reference reading: [Efficient String Concatenation in Python](http://skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/)

I am interested in this method. Can I use this to build the list and also join each item in the list into one-single string later when I return from the function (i.e. I need to print out the result). I am not too sure how to use this method. what is the first num?
**(Please visit the link because stackoverflow removes the quotes of the first num)**

1. Following up with #2, I am inserting integers into the list

   > > print result
   > >
   > > [1L, '.', 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L]
   > >
   > > print result[0]
   > >
   > > 1

I don't remember what that letter L stands for.....

I appreciate any helps! Thank you very much.

Comment: L stands for long.  you should probably preallocate your lists, eg `200000*[0L]`

Comment: if i want to print a million digits, should i preallocate the 1million * [0L]??? i see the advantage of preallocation. i think it eliminates the news to do compute the index, allocate memory, etc for each iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Please try to limit questions to one topic, rather than asking several unrelated questions at once.)

If you want to know how much of a difference a change like moving something out of a loop makes, you need to benchmark it yourself.  Search for `timeit`.

Appending to a string and to a list are completely different beasts.

Strings are immutable--you don't append to them.  `a += 'x'` doesn't append 'x' to a; it creates an entirely new string, making it O(n).  This can be inefficient when appending a lot of strings, since it becomes O(n^2).  (Note, though, that CPython optimizes this particular case when there are no other references to `a`, eliminating the extra copy.  Not all Python implementations can do this.)

This problem doesn't exist with lists: lists are mutable.  Appending to a list is O(1), so appending to them in a loop in efficient.  (It will periodically need to reallocate the list to make room for new items, but that's efficient.)

If you're generating a lot of data to insert into a list, it's often preferable to use a generator function, but you don't have to.

In Python 2, `1L` declares a long, rather than an int; see http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex.

Answer (score 1):

Appending to a list is not costly. Appending to a *string* is costly.

This is because strings in Python are immutable, so every time you append, a completely new string is made. Lists, however, are mutable, so appending to a list simply adds a single item at the end.

The backing implementations of lists in most Python implementations are arrays, so lists that grow over time *will* need to be re-allocated a few times if initialized as a smaller size, but since most implementations tend to use an exponential growth factor for allocation sizes, it's not all that much of a problem (and if you wanted, you could avoid it by pre-allocating the entire length via something like `my_list = [None]*1000000` for a list of a million `None`s).